# how to properly cleanup libuv across a duktape app soft reloads

Tags: c, libuv, duktape

I'm using libuv with duktape and my app needs to be able to reload itself live.
is there an official proper way to "cleanup" or "restart" libuv?

I'm already doing "uv_fs_req_cleanup" but I'm worried there'll be memory leaks if the entire libuv loop isn't somehow "destroyed".